# How to publish a ClickOnce application on Sharepoint?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, clickonce, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I'm developping a tool which should be published as a ClickOnce signed application on a Sharepoint website.

The problem is that, when executing the `.application` executable from Sharepoint, I get an error whith the following sentence (in french):

```
Le fichier <nom de l'appli>.exe.config possède un hachage calculé différent de celui spécifié dans le manifeste.
```

in english:

```
File, <application name>.exe.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
```

Having some knowledge on digital signature, I understand that the `.config` file was modified after publication by some mysterious way...

Moreover, by publishing my application locally, I never get this error.

Then I assume it comes from Sharepoint which should modify `.config` files...

Answer (score 1):

I work around this issue by simply telling Visual Studio to use `.deploy` file extension.

This can be set under *Project properties>Publish>Options>Deployment* and then check `Use ".deploy" file extension`